# list only last 24 hours created files in unix

Tags: unix, find, unix-timestamp, ctime

I want to display the files which are created 24hrs ago but the below command is giving 2012,2013 year files also any suggestions.

```
**sdtt02 [c_t2] 406: find /users/c_t2/ws/ -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'ws' ! -name 'binaries' ! -name 'delivery' ! -name 'cause' -ctime 1**
/users/c_t2/ws/Rlinp53.nic
/users/c_t2/ws/Rlinp55.nic
/users/c_t2/ws/new.sh
/users/c_t2/ws/file
/users/c_t2/ws/Rlinp53.nic%
/users/c_t2/ws/.linuxemuver.swp

sdtt02 [c_t2] 407: ls -lrt /users/c_t2/ws/Rlinp53.nic
-rwxr-xr-x 1 c_2 dhs3 89 Oct 22  2007 /users/c_t2/ws/Rlinp53.nic
sdtt02 [c_t2] 408: ls -lrt /users/c_t2/ws/Rlinp55.nic
-rwxr-xr-x 1 c_t2 dhs3 70 Apr 22  2008 /users/c_t2/ws/Rlinp55.nic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all files created in the last 24 hours in a particular specific directory and its sub-directories:

```
find /users/c_t2/ws/ -ctime -1 -ls
```

If you want to find all files modified:

```
find /users/c_t2/ws/ -mtime -1 -ls
```